# Multiple .dockerignore files in same directory

Tags: docker

In the same directory I have two `Dockerfiles` and I would like to add a separate `.dockerignore` for each of them.

Currently, I have:

```
Dockerfile.npm
Dockerfile.nginx
```

But can I have something like this?:

```
.dockerignore.npm
.dockerignore.nginx
```

Answer (score 22):

You can now use multiple `.dockerignore` files in Docker.

Firstly you need to enable BuildKit mode; this is done either by setting:

`export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`

or by adding this configuration:

`{ "features": { "buildkit": true } }`

to the Docker daemon configuration in `~/.docker/daemon.json` and restarting the daemon. This will be enabled by default in future.

You also need to prefix the name of your `.dockerignore` file with the Dockerfile name.

So if your Dockerfile is called `OneApp.Dockerfile` the ignore file needs to be called `OneApp.Dockerfile.dockerignore`.

All taken from this comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12886#issuecomment-480575928

Comment: >  So if your Dockerfile is called OneApp.Dockerfile the ignore file needs to be called OneApp.dockerignore

Shouldn't it be `OneApp.Dockerfile.dockerignore`?

Comment: No, it's not a `.Dockerfile`, it's a `.dockerignore` file.

Comment: @BrianDiPalma The linked issue only mentions appending `.dockerignore` to the specified docker file (as  @koshmaster said). Where's the info about OneApp.dockerignore?

Comment: @BrianDiPalma and @stackblow, if it helps I've successfully implemented this. The filname needs to be `OneApp.Dockerfile.dockerignore`

Comment: @koshmaster I've implemented as I said in my comment. Maybe the code just checks for start and file extension.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think you can specify a different ignore file while doing a build. But since you are creating a separate file, you can write a shell script

**build_nginx.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
ln -fs .dockerignore.nginx .dockerignore
docker build -f Dockerfile.nginx -t nginxbuild .
```

**build_npm.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
ln -fs .dockerignore.npm .dockerignore
docker build -f Dockerfile.npm -t npmbuild .
```

If you need to use it with `docker-compose` then you need to separate folders for ngixn and npm and then can have their individual `.dockerignore` file. In your `docker-compose.yml` file you need specify the name of the directory as the context

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, but I would like to use them in `docker-compose` file later. Is there a way to use this in the compose file?

Comment: Update the answer

Comment: the solution you propose with docker-compose will cause problems for the `Dockerfile`. Dockerfile won't have the context of the parent diretory so you want be able to `COPY` stuff for example

Comment: Wrappers Are Evil

Answer (score 1):

Multiple dockerignore files or specifying which dockerignore file to use is currently not supported by Docker.

See this issue on Github: [**Add support for specifying .dockerignore file with -i/--ignore**](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12886)