# Is there an easy way to copy specific portions of a directory into a Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker

Let's say my package structure looks something like this:

```
.
├── mypackage
│   ├── ignore_this_subpackage
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── ignore_me.py
│   ├── include_this_subpackage
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── shared_library.py
│   └── my_main_subpackage
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── main.py
├── __init__.py
├── Dockerfile
└── requirements.txt
```

And let's say my Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN mkdir -p /opt/mypackage
COPY mypackage/ /opt/mypackage/

ENV PYTHONPATH="/opt/$PYTHONPATH"
WORKDIR /opt/mypackage/my_main_subpackage
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"]
```

As you can see, I am copying everything from `mypackage`. However, I really only need two of the nested directories. Ideally, I would like to exclude certain sub-modules. But because the `main.py` references the other shared library with its fully qualified module name, I do need to keep the full directory structure.

In this simplified example, it would be pretty easy to just copy the individual files and folders by hand with multiple COPY statements. But in reality, this actually represents a much larger project with far too many files for that to be feasible.

I'm wondering if anyone else has come up with any elegant solutions to this problem? I had thought about running two calls to `mkdir -p` to create the nested subdirectories, and then just using two `COPY` statements to copy the files I needed. However the problem with this is that I still need to have the blank `__init__.py` files at each directory level, otherwise the imports will fail. And I'm not aware of any utilities out there for seeding each directory in a tree with blank `__init__.py` files.

Is there any way to do a slightly more sophisticated `COPY` command that either excludes certain directories, or only includes certain matches, or somesuch? Thanks.

Comment: did you try the `.dockerignore`, you can what you would like to exclude, and then maybe just do `COPY . .`

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) of `.dockerignore`, you can use this file at the root of your directory to tell docker not to copy everything.

your diretory strucutre would look like this

```
.
├── mypackage
│   ├── ignore_this_subpackage
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── ignore_me.py
│   ├── include_this_subpackage
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── shared_library.py
│   └── my_main_subpackage
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── main.py
├── __init__.py
├── Dockerfile
|──.dockerignore
└── requirements.txt
```

and your `.dockerignore` file would contain what you need to ignore

```
ignore_this_subpackage
```

And then `COPY` command in your `Dockerfile` would look like

```
COPY . .
```

Comment: That's very interesting, as I didn't know about `.dockerignore` files. Unfortunately I suppose that means my question was incomplete. I can't actually use that in this case because I have other Dockerfiles in the same repository that do require the subpackage that this one is ignoring. In actuality, and in contrast to my simplified example, this is essentially a large "monorepo" which contains multiple projects, and multiple Dockerfiles. Sorry for omitting that detail.

Comment: I see there is a reference to using multiple .dockerignore in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344158/multiple-dockerignore-files-in-same-directory