# docker-compose namespacing for dockerignore

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

`docker-compose` version info:

```
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
docker-py version: 3.7.3
CPython version: 3.6.8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
```

I have several Dockerfiles and docker-compose files named in the following conventions

```
Dockerfile.a
Dockerfile.b
Dockerfile.c
docker-compose.x.dev.yml
docker-compose.x.prod.yml
docker-compose.y.dev.yml
docker-compose.y.prod.yml
```

Where `docker-compose.x.prod.yml` might look like

```
version: '3'

services:
  a:
    image: service_a
    container_name: cont_a
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.a
  b:
    image: service_b
    container_name: cont_b
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.b
```

and I might make the following call

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.x.prod.yml -f docker-compose.x.dev.yml build
```

How should I name my dockerignore file? Which of any of the following do I need?

```
Dockerfile.a.dockerignore
docker-compose.x.dockerignore
docker-compose.x.prod.dockerignore
docker-compose.x.dev.dockerignore
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are not using the newer BuildKit backend, then the [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) must be in the `context:` directory and must be named exactly `.dockerignore`.  Neither [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) nor the [docker-compose `build:` block](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) have the ability to provide an alternate name for it.  In your example, both services will always use the same `.dockerignore` file.

This means that any file either one of the services needs can't be listed in the `.dockerignore` file.  In practice, it probably means you also don't want to blindly `COPY .` into an image, since that will contain quite a bit of content that an individual image won't need; you will need to be more selective about what you `COPY` in.

BuildKit has been available in Docker for a while, and is on by default in many installations.  If you have at least Docker 19.03, the BuildKit backend does provide a path to do this; see [@ChrisJohnson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643156) for details.

Comment: what about https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12886#issuecomment-480575928 ?

Comment: Aside from that GitHub issue, I can't find any mention of that functionality in the official documentation.  (It's not mentioned in the BuildKit repo or the [Docker documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) on BuildKit.)  I don't have a good setup off hand to try it.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help, I also saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344158/multiple-dockerignore-files-in-same-directory and figured since you can override with docker compose (e.g. `docker-compose -f <file1> -f <file2>`) was hoping that I could have multiple ignore files for each context. So I have two compose files (`x` and `y`), but all three dockerfiles (`a`, `b`, `c`) require the same build context with varied ignore files

Comment: @DavidMaze your answer is no longer accurate.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson BuildKit is on for most newer Dockers, but definitely not everywhere.  I've updated my answer to acknowledge that this is an option on BuildKit referencing yours.  (The core Docker documentation doesn't mention this at all, only the release notes you link to.)

Comment: Very true. This will help people understand what options apply to their build env. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiple dockerignore files, one per dockerfile, if you use BuildKit. This isn't available when not using BuildKit. If you're not using BuildKit, see [@DavidMaze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59726679).

Builds for the normally-named `Dockerfile` use the normally-named `.dockerignore` file, whether you use BuildKit or not. This is the classic default that we're all accustomed to.

For other dockerfile names, the name for the ignore file should be the dockerfile name + a `.dockerignore` suffix. For example, BuildKit builds for a dockerfile named `Dockerfile.test` would use an ignore file named `Dockerfile.test.dockerignore`. And if that specially-named ignore file doesn't exist, the build would fall back and use the usual `.dockerignore` file.

This features was added in Docker v19.03 - see [the release notes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/19.03/). This is a BuildKit-only feature. To use BuildKit, you can either `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` in the build environment, or specify it for the duration of individual commands like `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build ...`.